# searching VB6 code

Tags: events, vb6, asp-classic

I've inherited a ASP/VB6 code base (not my forte... yet) and I'm trying tease it apart to figure out the cause on an error message I'm receiving when running the app.

I've traced it back through an event that is being raised in on of my classes. Is there away in windows I can search the bulk of the code base for where it is being consumed? 
Ctrl-F (and selecting Current Project) has not sufficed.

The linux geek in me is saying dump it to a *insert distro* box and just grep for the sucker. But there's got to be some way in the IDE to do it... right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have any new version of VS (2003,5,8) installed, just use the "Find in Files" feature and point it at the VB6 folders.

Other than that, most "notepad" replacements (textpad, notepad+) offer a "Find in Files" as well.

Comment: Found it... VS's "Find In Files" was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

> But there's got to be some way in the IDE to do it... right?

No. There are some plugins for the IDE, such as the [MZ Tools](http://www.mztools.com/) that *might* help. Otherwise, just use the `find` tool from the Windows command line. Not nearly as comfortable as using `grep`, of course.

Comment: I had MZ Tools installed but never noticed how handy the search was. thx.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.mztools.com/index.aspx
MZ-Tools 3.0 is a  freeware add-in for  Visual Basic 6.0, Visual Basic 5.0 and the Visual Basic For Applications editor.

It is essential for anyone still working with VB 6.0

It has an enhanced find feature as well as a calling Procedure similar to .net Find usage.

Answer (score 0):

I have a large legacy code-base in VB6 which needs maintenance from time to time and I have used Microsoft Desktop Search on my local copy to help find variable and method names across the code files.

Also [Grep](http://www.interlog.com/~tcharron/grep.html) is available for Windows.